# Why using 'case' in this way doesn't work?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

```
CASE 
WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT content  FROM table1 WHERE username='amir' AND content = "something") 
THEN UPDATE users SET Score=Score+1 WHERE username='amir'
INSERT INTO table1 (username,content)VALUES('amir',"somthing")
END;
```

Why this query doesn't work and how to fix it, and if there is a better way to do this, how?

Comment: Is your question about MySQL or SQLite? Tagging both doesn't really make sense (and otherwise you need to explicitly explain this in your question). Note that in most SQL dialects `case` is only for producing values, not for an alternative 'if .. else ..'

Comment: MySql allows this CASE  syntax in procedures only https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.  I should add that the logic of what you are describing also doesn't really make sense.  If the row exists, then you update all rows for the user?

Comment: well I'm dealing with this in both SQLite and MySQL  and of course the answer may Differ by the database

Comment: Then you need to make that explicit in your question.

Comment: well the logic is that if the content submitted by the user is new then add one to the score of the user (the user name is the primary key then there wont be more than on record to be updated)and add the new content to the table1

Comment: You are attempting to use `case` in a way it wasn't designed for.  You have to apply the logic in a completely different way.  You could do it in the application before the database comes into play, or you could write a stored procedure with if else logic, if your database engine supports that sort of thing.  I don't use either sqllite or mySql so I wouldn't know.